# Spritekit line with round corner

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I use SKShapeNode to draw some lines from point A to point B. The line is pretty wide and I need to round the corners to make it nicer.

After some search, there is a CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect but I'm not sure it can draw line in diagonal.

I have tried to add a circle on the line start and line end but the result is not perfect, especially if I use glowWidth on both the circle and the line.

This is how I draw a line:

```
SKShapeNode *yourline = [SKShapeNode node];
CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, from.x, from.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, to.x, to.y);
yourline.path = pathToDraw;
[yourline setStrokeColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[nodeGridLines addChild:yourline];
```

I'm new to SpriteKit and maybe there is another way to do what I want.
And if I could use some texture on my line, it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lineCap property of the SKShapeNode.

```
    UIBezierPath *linePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [linePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(500, 300)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(550, 350)];
    SKShapeNode *lineNode = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithPath:linePath.CGPath];
    lineNode.lineCap = kCGLineCapRound;
    lineNode.lineWidth = 10;
    [self addChild:lineNode];
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath i can set kCGLineCapRound to have a line with round corners.

I'm still searching a way to apply some texture on my line.

Answer (score 0):

The Swift 5.x command now looks like this:

```
lineNode.lineCap = CGLineCap.round
```

Comment: Or simply `lineNode.lineCap = .round`.